# Error with signing a Mac Application

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I signed my mac app to submint it to app store, but I get a error:

> Invalid code signing. The executable "MY APP" must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile.

How can I Fix this?

Answer (score 0):

check that Certificates at Provision profile include your certificate from Account Certificates (at right bar)

[image: show me]